# Possible to place two workspaces on one screen in X Window?

Tags: linux, gnome, x11

Sometimes I'd like to copy write something from one window to my editor or compare something.

So if I can put two workspace2 in one screen, so I can easily drag two windows to different workspace and get both fullscreen, and then start work on one of them.

Also I can buy another monitor, but it seems to cost too much and as the screen is getting bigger, two windows in one screen is acceptable.

Does X support a solution for this?

**EDIT:**
I think what I want is related to this topic:

[`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can look at other windows managers, such as [wmii](http://wmii.suckless.org/), [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) or [ratpoison](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/) changing the workspace paradigm and allow a better use of screen estate.

Comment: awesome seems support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need it dragging wwindows from one Workspace to another, the **Desktop Effects** in Linux gives you exactly what you want with all your workspaces on a cube, which you can:

- rootate with the mouse
- drag windows across the workspaces.

For more Info: you may refer to this [Google books Link](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=yZ7Z6Wq3EdcC&pg=PA278&lpg=PA278&dq=Linux+Desktop+Effects+Cube&source=bl&ots=yXGVLbMeZL&sig=dW2g4ozcCXXEFU_71MhlK_xnMuk&hl=en&ei=eEeSSp_8I5CpkAXKoqjDAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7#v=onepage&q=&f=false)

---

However, this is in no way comparable to a 2-monitor workstation. You may even consider an old CRT which are available for Dirt cheap prices now

Comment: Actually I mean two workspace in same screen at the same time. Maybe I should call this windows layout, automatically align different windows in the same screen.